# mpg123 not working in ide but works in cmd

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

'mpg123' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

when I run it on Visual studio 2019.

But works well when I run using cmd

I'm using the code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-text-speech-python/

Comment: Generally speaking, this means the `PATH` variable -- determining where to look for executables -- is different between the two processes.

Comment: This is not at all a valid Python question. It *could* well be a good Visual Studio question (along the lines of "why does Visual Studio have a different PATH than my cmd shell?"), if edited appropriately (meaning: remove the python tag, add a visual studio tag, and actually show both PATHs as well as the executable's actual location).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please explain (in your question post) why this is tagged `python`?

Comment: May I know how do I check the path for visual studio?